# Java - Keeping a socket client alive after finishing reading

Tags: java, sockets, client

I'm a bit new to sockets in Java but here is my question:

I have written a client thread class that will request to connect to a server, created by another application (therefore I do not have a class made for server class). Basically, this application will transmit a certain number of bytes and close the server side of the socket. I have been fully able to receive and process those bytes.

My question is can the client side socket be told to "wait" for another connection from the same address/port to be available and then continue to read bytes? (In essence, I run the application, it reads the bytes and finished, then I run the application again, and the client will still be able to read)

Here is the code for my client thread:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread{

    private Socket soc;
    private InputStream in;
    private String host;
    private int port;

public ClientThread(String host, int port)
{
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    soc = null;
    in = null;
}

public boolean connectToServer()
{
    try {
        soc = new Socket(host, port);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        System.err.println("Connection accepted: "+soc);
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to determine IP of host: "+host+".");
        return false;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating or accessing the socket.");
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: "+host+".");
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean disconnectFromServer()
{
    try {
        if(in != null)
            in.close();
        if(soc != null && soc.isConnected()) {
            soc.close();
            soc = null;
            System.err.println("Connection successfully closed!");
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: "+e);
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        int sz = 0;
        byte[] tmp = new byte[25];
        while(true)
        {
                if(sz == -1) {
                    sz = 0;
                }
                sz += in.read(tmp, sz, 25-sz);
                System.out.println(sz);
                if(sz == 25) {
                    tmp = new byte[25];
                    for(byte b: tmp)
                        System.out.print(b);
                    sz = 0;
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }

        } 
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection closed abruptly.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: "+host+".");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will receive a socket when `accept()` returns, and as long as that socket does not get closed then the connection remains open.

So when you run the application for the first time, then shut down the server and then run it for the second time, I think the connection will be broken and you have to re-initialize it.

The `isConnected()` method will give you a false result, because this will always return `true` if the socket is not closed explicitly by you at the client side.

If you want to be sure, you can run your client-server connection once, then shut down the server, restart it and then try reading/writing from/to the server. If the connection is broken, you'll get -1 as a result from reading and an `IOException`from writing.

Comment: Ok yes I believe that when the application finishes the connection is closed. Is there an efficient way of having the client side reconnect automatically if a new server-side socket is available?

Comment: Maybe you can write a `Thread` which checks the connection every so often with the methods I described in my answer (just do a read or write, I guess read would be the easiest one) and when the connection is lost, just call a method to open a connection.

Comment: that might work. But I have another question if its not too much trouble. Lets say I manually disconnect my client before the app has transmitted all of its data. Then I want to reconnect my client to finish reading the rest of the data. Is that possible? I have TCPview open and it says that the socket for the app is still Listening after I've disconnected the client.